# Homomorphism under addition $\varphi :\mathbb{R}[x] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}[x]$ where $\varphi(p(x))=\frac{d}{dx}(xp(x))$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

I am wondering if $\varphi :\mathbb{R}[x] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}[x]$ where $\varphi(p(x))=\frac{d}{dx}(xp(x))$ is really is a homomorphism. I can't think of a situation where it is not because I'm thinking that even $\mathbb{R}\subset \mathbb{R}[x]$. So if I had $p(x)=1, q(x)=2$
$$\varphi(p(x)+q(x))=\frac{d}{dx}((x)(1))+\frac{d}{dx}((x)(2))=1+2=\\=\varphi(p(x))+\varphi(q(x))$$

Is any of my reasoning wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The main thing is that what you have done for **specific** $p(x),q(x)$ has to be done for **all** $p(x),q(x)$.

Comment: Thanks, I feel that I can do that more generally by $$\varphi=((p(x)+q(x))=\frac{d}{dx}(xp(x))+\frac{d}{dx}(x(q(x))=p(x)+xp'(x)+q(x)+xq'(x)=\varphi(p(x))+\varphi(q(x))$$ is this correct?

Comment: It is so simple, $\varphi(p(x)+q(x))=\frac{d}{dx}(x (p(x)+q(x)))=\frac{d}{dx}(xp(x))+\frac{d}{dx}(x(q(x))=\varphi(p(x))+\varphi(q(x)).$

Comment: okay so I don't need to show the product rule, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Yes, it is a homomorphism of groups but not a homomorphism of rings.

Comment: Was was this question deleted and re-posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a homomorphism of rings even if it is additive. 
In fact, for $p(x)=x, q(x)=x$, we have
$$\varphi(p(x)q(x))=3x^2\neq \varphi(p(x)) \varphi(q(x))=2x\times 2x=4x^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

The maps $p(x) \mapsto xp(x)$ and $p(x) \mapsto p'(x)$ are both additive and so is its composition $\varphi$.